# finding parameters for measured values

Tags: numerical-methods

From a physical system I got the following relation:

$$
c_M = \sqrt{ \frac{c_s}{\sin{\alpha_s}} } \sqrt{ \frac{L}{\Delta t - 2 t_s} } 
$$

From measurements multiple pairs of $(L,\Delta t)$ are known, $c_s$, $\alpha_s$ are given constants.  It is further known that $c_M$ and $t_s$ are constant values for all $(L,\Delta t)$.

How can I find the values for $c_M$ and $t_s$?

Comment: Square your expression; isolate $\Delta t$ as lhs. This looks like a linear regression.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thank you, unfortunately it's too long ago when I did this last time so my eyes are not used to see this anymore...